# Error while uploadiing image on firebase storage using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

Here is what I have done:

```
onPressed: () async {
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera);
    print('${file?.path}');
    if (file == null) return;

    String uniqueFilename = DateTime.now()
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch
        .toString();
    Reference referenceRoot =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    Reference referanceDirImages =
        referenceRoot.child('images');
    Reference referanceimgtoupload =
        referanceDirImages.child(uniqueFilename);
 try {
      await referanceimgtoupload
          .putFile(File(file.path));
      imageUrl =
          await referanceimgtoupload.getDownloadURL();
      print('here its done');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error in try');
      print(e);
    }
  },
```

and getting  this error after getting image url printed

```
 E/flutter (31775): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/no-bucket] No default storage bucket could be found. Ensure you have correctly followed the Getting Started guide.
E/flutter (31775): #0      _throwNoBucketError (package:firebase_storage/src/firebase_storage.dart:221:3)
E/flutter (31775): #1      FirebaseStorage.instanceFor (package:firebase_storage/src/firebase_storage.dart:67:9)
E/flutter (31775): #2      FirebaseStorage.instance (package:firebase_storage/src/firebase_storage.dart:50:28)
E/flutter (31775): #3      _RegistrationState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:softgrid/screens/registration.dart:305:51)
E/flutter (31775): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31775):
```

Comment: can you recheck if you've created the storage on console?

Answer (score 1):

check if you pass the bucket url in initialization

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
        appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
        projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
        storageBucket: 'MY_BUCKET'
    )
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
```

your `MY_BUCKET` can should be visibl in your console and

it will be something like `abc-xyz-123.storage.firebase.com.` where `abc-xyz-123` is related to your projectID